# create a data structure in controller using c# and pass it into view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC4. i am using doing some chart function in my asp.net mvc application.

i searched and found a js library called Chart.js

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-data-structure
the data structure is like below:

```js
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};
```

i am trying to read data from db in my controller and pass this data into the view but always failed to display the chart.

i tried this in controller:

```html
int[] intArray = new int[7];
intArray[0] = 34;
intArray[1] = 1;
intArray[2] = 2;
intArray[3] = 23;
intArray[4] = 11;
intArray[5] = 11;
intArray[6] = 11;
ViewBag.proinfo = Json(intArray, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet).Data;
```

and then in view:

```html
 {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            ViewBag.proinfo
        }
```

but this not work for me.the chart can not display.

how to create this data structure in c# controller and pass it to view?

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily assign value in ViewBag.proinfo

```
ViewBag.proinfo = intArray;
```

you forgot to define **data** in json in **View**

```
{
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data:ViewBag.proinfo
}
```

Comment: Not working... no matter how i try, it only works when i hard code in view like this: data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],   which means can not pass from controller,   is there something wrong with the array type of data?

Comment: what are you getting in **ViewBag.proinfo** on view? did you check?

Comment: use `var proinfo = ViewBag.proinfo as int[];` to retrieve data in View

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in controller:

> ViewBag.proinfo = intArray

in view

```html
 {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.proinfo));
        }
```

I assume u're using MVC Razor symtax